# Answer on poster-deleted question vanishes without trace

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

I answered a question last night and had a couple of comments back and forth with the poster. This morning I wondered how it turned out and went to my profile to look. There's no trace of it in my profile under "answers" or "all actions", and I don't know where else to look. I happened to find a link to the question so I can see that it was deleted by the poster, presumably because it wasn't very good.

My memory isn't great, so it's really disconcerting to have Stack Overflow tell me I did nothing last night, when I'm pretty pretty sure I did something. I understand I can't see the deleted question without more reputation, but it would be nice if there was some indication that there's *something* missing from the record, even if it just said "Answer - Question deleted". The way it is now **feels like gaslighting**.

Is there any way currently for me to see that I answered a question that was subsequently deleted, assuming I don't have a link to the question? If not, I'd like to request that as a feature.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/149097

Comment: @zondo Neat, that's just what I'm looking for. Sorry to be dense but is that URL accessible from my profile or do I just need to bookmark it?

Comment: If you look at the answers tab of the activity tab of your profile, there's a link at the bottom: `recently deleted answers`.

Comment: @zondo Awesome, I see that now. Sorry for the bother.

Comment: Also, if you have 10k rep, you can search [`user:me deleted:1`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1) .